# Angular $templateCache Does Not Work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I am having an issue with Angular's $templateCache in ie10 specifically, but is also an issue in ie11. It works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Here is my template definition, in templates.js:

```
angular.module('app').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
  'use strict';

  $templateCache.put('/views/page.html',
    "<div class=\"page-header row\">\n" +
    "  <div class=\"col-xs-6\">\n" +
    "    <span class=\"heading title\">{{pageTitle}}</span>\n"
    ...
  );
}]);
```

I include the templates.js at the top of the page in the `<head>`, like:

```
<script src="/js/templates.js"></script>
```

And finally I consume the templates in my routes definition, here:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      redirectTo:'/page'
    })
    .when('/page', {
      controller: 'pageController',
      templateUrl:'/views/page.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo:'/'
    });
}]);
```

Again, it all works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not IE10. The only other information I can think to provide is that the app is not at the root level, it is http://example.com/app. but the templates are indeed stored in http://example.com/views.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is a JSFiddle which actually works in IE, but I'm not sure if that's because of how JSFiddle handles the browser frame. If you copy and paste the code into an index.html, and run it on your server, it will not work in IE.
http://jsfiddle.net/v9sv7jdL/2/

Comment: can you try making it views/ instead of /views/? is stupid but then is also ie so...

Comment: I'm just working on a test app, where I am referencing views/, but its still not working in ie. I'll put it in a JSFiddle.

Comment: i don't know what to tell you is working on my ie10

Comment: In the JSFiddle it works. But if you copy and paste the example into index.html, drop it in the root of your webserver, and run it, it doesnt work.

Comment: do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: Update: I've the basic example working in IE. Turns out compatibility mode was enabled. I've even moved the index.html file into an /app/ subdirectory and it still works as well, at http://localhost/app/#/page. However it still doesn't work my main app, so I'll try to figure out what is different.

Answer (score 0):

In this case we actually had special logic in our app for IE. It adds a ?ts= to the end of our requests, which of course, does not exist in the templateCache.